# How to store product addons in Firestore DB?

Tags: javascript, database, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

So, I have a product saved to my Firestore DB, but I havent figure out how I can manage product addons, for example lets say the item was a pizza, and the person wanted extra cheese or extra tomatoes. Im not sure the best way to map this info in my DB. Lets say the following is my product entry (removed things like added timestamps for simplicities sake)

```
{
   itemName (String)
   itemBasePrice (number)
   itemStock (number)
   availableAt (array (of stores))
}
```

What is the best way for me to map product addons like extra cheese, or pepperoni, etc. should I make a DB entry for each addon? I feel like its expensive to make 100 calls from the DB to add one item to your basket?

Comment: can you refer to this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7d5Zeic63s Is it helpful?

Comment: Are you talking about an item order as in a person has selected extra cheese on their pizza, or the item definition as in extra cheese is an option available for the item 'pizza'?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Both really. So Im not sure how I would store it in the DB. And how I would store it in the cart, I have an idea but it means that addons will be a seperate document/DB entry.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description you provided, I think for this use case, nested fields or arrays should be the best option. I suggest you refer to  this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data) and [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html) on how to structure data and use of arrays. If there is more information that needs to be tracked for each add ons, then you can consider using sub-collections. There are pros and cons for each way to structure the data. It really depends on how you are planning to use/query the data.

Comment: @Jordz2203 Posted an answer, Is it helpful?